# Login validation for connect to application C#

Tags: c#, authentication, sqldatareader, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I created login validation for connect to application but now i have problem that during connecting to app say me that errors with shutdown connections.

My script for validation:

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [Login]
 (
   username varchar(30) CHECK (username is not null AND username <> ''),
   email varchar(30),
   [password] varchar(50),
   UNIQUE (username)
 )

 INSERT INTO dbo.Login values('admin', 'Email@seznam.cz', HASHBYTES('md5',convert(varchar(50),'root')))
```

C#:

```
class LoginValidation : Login
{
    public string connection = "Data Source=RADEK-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Evidence;Integrated Security=True;";
    public string loginVal, passwordVal;

    public LoginValidation(string login, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                sql.Open();


                using (SqlCommand selectLogin = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Login WHERE username = @login", sql))
                {
                    selectLogin.Parameters.Clear();
                    SqlParameter subjektParam = new SqlParameter("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
                    subjektParam.Value = login;
                    selectLogin.Parameters.Add(subjektParam);
                    selectLogin.Prepare();

                    using (SqlDataReader readerLogin = selectLogin.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (readerLogin.Read())
                        {
                            if (readerLogin.IsDBNull(0) || readerLogin.IsDBNull(2))
                                continue;


                            loginVal = readerLogin.GetString(0);
                            passwordVal = readerLogin.GetString(2);
                        }
                    }
                    sql.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Chyba: " + e);
        }

        if (login == loginVal && password == passwordVal)
        {
            Main main = new Main();
            main.Show();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Přihlašovací jméno nebo heslo neni správné");
    }
}
```

Output errors:

```
e   {"A fatal internal error connection."}  System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

INPUT DATA:

```
login - > admin
password - > root
```

Please, can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** You re invoking `ExecuteNonQuery()` which is not required as you are invoking `select` command.

**Remove this  :**

```
selectLogin.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Problem 2:**  use `||` for Logical `OR` Operation.

Try This :

```
if (readerLogin.IsDBNull(0) || readerLogin.IsDBNull(2))
continue;
```

**Solution 2:**  `Hashbytes` can not be `decrypted` as they are one direction.  The only way to Resolve the problem is to hash the `user password` value and compare it with the existing `password value` in database.

Comment: its correct now sry, now i have hash password in DB. How can i unhash this password for validation to login app.

Because now login == loginVal is correct but password == passwordVal is incorrect because passwordVal return me hash password.

Comment: @RadekTarant: sorry i'm really unware of encrypting and decrypting, it depends on which mechanism you used for encryting.

Comment: i using only this: HASHBYTES('md5',convert(varchar(50),'root'

Comment: @RadekTarant: Hashbytes can not be decrypted , you need to Hash the given user password and compare with existing one in database , see my edited answer with section `solution 2`

Answer (score 0):

change your try block statements with this

```
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            sql.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Login WHERE username = @login";
            SqlCommand selectLogin = new SqlCommand(query , sql);
            selectLogin.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@login",login)); 
            SqlDataReader readerLogin = selectLogin.ExecuteReader())                    
            while (readerLogin.Read())
            {
               if (readerLogin.IsDBNull(0) || readerLogin.IsDBNull(2))
                  continue;
               loginVal = readerLogin.GetString(0);
               passwordVal = readerLogin.GetString(2);
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Really thx for help, but my problem was fixed i used help from @Sudhakar. But now i need help with unhash password. Format for hash password is HASHBYTES('md5',convert(varchar(50),'root'.